# PowerShell, CIS, Win server 2012

Tags: windows, powershell, server

How do I extract all Group Policy Objects through PowerShell so I can compare them to the CIS Benchmark configuration guidelines for a safe and secure environment?

No code provided as I am an intern and looking to learn.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question? This doesn't seem like a programming issue... Not at this point anyway.

Comment: for example, 2.2.1 (L1) Ensure 'Access Credential Manager as a trusted caller' is set to 'No One', and I need to check whether this is really true on my server

Comment: Search the web for which gpo/registry key is responsible for the setting, I guess?

Comment: 2 weeks looking for but no answer found

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Export all GPO via the below.

```
Get-GPO -All | Foreach-Object {$_.GenerateReport('html') | Out-File "$($_.DisplayName).htm"}
```

To ensure your GPO is CIS compliant you can't really just run a PowerShell script and let it update them all. Your best bet is to use one of the supplied [Microsoft administrative GPO templates](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43413).

If you have already set up your environment then you can download the template above and compare it to your current GPOs using the [Microsoft Policy Analyzer](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/22/new-tool-policy-analyzer/) to ensure you are meeting the security baseline standards set out by [CIS Benchmark](https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-benchmarks/) and the [Australian Information Security manual](https://acsc.gov.au/infosec/ism/index.htm).

Comment: Thank you very much! I am an intern in the company and I was given the task to check the server on cis via Powershell in order that I learned powershell. And should do everything through the powershell without any other programs and files

Comment: Hi Daniel, I updated the answer that should get you a nice report. You will need to look  through you CIS Configuration guidelines, find the policies and ensure they match.